# Reference data internally in Bash script

Tags: bash, unix

The following will read from an external file and output the data:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='|' read hostname nickname; do

echo $hostname $nickname

done < "list.dat"
```

Where the list.dat file is:

```
firstserver|joe
secondserver|henry
thirdserver|jack
```

But I'd like to actually store the list.dat in the script itself (not externally) but don't know how to reference it as a variable/array and read from it with the same results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) pass a variable or string as I think you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="firstserver|joe
secondserver|henry
thirdserver|jack"

while IFS='|' read hostname nickname; do

echo $hostname $nickname

done <<< "$input"
```

Comment: This seems to work but not with the space after input and the =

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing it out. Quoting `$input` is also a good idea.

Comment: Keep in mind, there is a bug in `bash` prior to 4.3 that could cause problems with combining a local `IFS` setting with a here string. Using a here document may be safer.

Comment: `bash` does not apply word-splitting or path expansion to a parameter expanded as a here string, so the quotes are unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Try using a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='|' read hostname nickname; do
echo $hostname $nickname
done <<LIMIT
firstserver|joe
secondserver|henry
thirdserver|jack
LIMIT
```

Comment: Of course, if your values don't need to contain whitespace, it makes a lot more sense to use whitespace as the delimiter.  Then you don't need to muck with `IFS` at all.

Comment: Your solution also works, thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about 'here-document'

Answer (score 2):

If bash 4 is available to you, I'd use an associative array:

```
declare -A servers=(
    ["firstserver"]=joe
    ["secondserver"]=henry
    …
)

for hostname in "${!servers[@]}"; do
    echo "$hostname" "${servers[$hostname]}"
done
```

This assumes the hostnames are unique.